# Decomposition of fundamental dominant weight and decomposition of representations

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

I know that a a dominant weight is a positive integer combination of fundamental dominant weights. I also know that if a Lie group $G$ has an irreducible representation $V$, then $V=L(\lambda)$, where $L(\lambda)$ denotes an irreducible $G$-module of dominant way $\lambda$. I have read that in this case the mentioned decomposition of $\lambda$ as a positive integer combination of fundamental dominant weights $\lambda_i$ implies $L(\lambda)=\bigotimes_i L(\lambda_i)$. Is this true? Or there is a different decomposition of $L(\lambda)$?

Comment: If $\lambda = \sum_i \lambda_i \varpi_i$ is the expression of the weight $\lambda$ in the basis $(\varpi_1, \ldots)$ of fundamental weights, then $L(\lambda) \subseteq \bigotimes_i L(\lambda_i \varpi_i)$. (To prove this, it is enough to find a highest-weight vector on the right of weight $\lambda$, which is not hard). But the representation on the right is usually much larger than the one on the left.

Comment: Dear Joppy, thank you very much for your answer. Please can you also give me some references?